# How to parse JSON array to a spinner

Tags: java, android, json

I want to parse a JSON file with nested arrays and objects, and use the parsed info to populate a spinner.
Now I'm stuck in the progress window, only showing "loading"...I only want to extract the name tag (navn) to the spinner, and nsrID stored in a variable, for later use.

JSON format:

```
[
  {
    "nsrId": "1018038",
    "koordinatLatLng": [
      59.6908,
      9.04228
    ],
    "navn": "Gransherad barnehage",
    "fylkesnummer": "08",
    "kommunenummer": "0807",
    "alder": "1 - 5",
    "eierform": "Kommunal",
    "antallBarn": 26
  },
  {
    "nsrId": "1012983",
    "koordinatLatLng": [
      59.5763,
      9.19806
    ],
    "navn": "Trolldalen Gårdsbarnehage",
    "fylkesnummer": "08",
    "kommunenummer": "0807",
    "alder": "1 - 5",
    "eierform": "Privat",
    "antallBarn": 24
  },
```

etc...

My code:

```
    spinner = findViewById(R.id.barneHage_Spinner);

    hentJSON();
}

private void hentJSON() {
    showSimplProgressDialog(this, "loading...", "Henter Json", false);

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, barnehager_URL,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    Log.d("strrrrr", ">>" + response);

                    try {
                        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);

                        barnehageArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
                        JSONArray dataArray = obj.getJSONArray("navn");

                        for (int i = 0; i < dataArray.length(); i++) {
                            Barnehage model = new Barnehage();
                            JSONObject dataobj = dataArray.getJSONObject(i);

                            model.setNavn(dataobj.getString("navn"));
                           // model.setNsrId(dataArray.getNsrId(Integer.parseInt("nsrId")));

                            barnehageArrayList.add(model);
                        }

                        for (int i = 0; i < barnehageArrayList.size(); i++) {
                            names.add(barnehageArrayList.get(i).getNavn());
                        }
                        ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(BarneHager.this, simple_spinner_item, names);
                        spinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
                        removeSimpleProgressDialog();

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
```

I expect the output to be a spinner with the only values showing

```
1: Gransherad barnehage
2: Trolldalen Gårdsbarnehage
3: ..
4: ..
```

etc

Answer (score 0):

You have to add an item at zero position of your list

```
barnehageArrayList.add(0,new MODELCLASS("Select option"))
```

And add below code to populate your Spinner

```
SPINNER_NAME.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            if (position != 0) {

            } else {

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you were wrong when getting JSON array by `JSONArray dataArray = obj.getJSONArray("navn")`.

Let try using this code:

```
    @Override
    public void onResponse (String response) {
        try {
            JSONArray dataArray = new JSONArray(response);
            for (int i = 0; i < dataArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject dataobj = dataArray.getJSONObject(i);
```